# Show spinner.gif before DOM gets ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, animation

I got a page with lots of div, span and so .... and it took about 3-5 seconds before the DOM gets ready. So, I want to show a spinner before the DOM gets ready. I'm using jQuery.

## Update

How to Block user from clicking on the page before DOM gets ready ?

Answer (score 4):

In the html add the spinner and then remove it when the dom is ready.

html:

```
<img id="spinner" src="spinner.gif" />
```

js:

```
$(function(){
    $('#spinner').remove();
});
```